# How To Find Out That Which View Call The Context Menu In Android

Tags: android, eclipse, android-fragments

Hi guys I have a dynamic layout in android and all of its member have few basic option so I made a simple context menu. I am facing problem A I am unable to find that which view call the context menu as i need the text of that view to call next activity
Help Me Guys.
Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 0):

The `View` that the menu is created for is passed into [`onCreateContextMenu()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu) as the second parameter.

Comment: But I Want To Find That Out InSide 
onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)

Comment: Create a class member `View` initialized to `null`, and set it to the parameter `View` passed in `onCreateContextMenu()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
    int position = acmi.position;
    ...
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

When you know position you can get the value from your adapter: adapter.getItem(position).